# How to exclude subdomain from RewrtieRule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I know this question has been asked a million times, but the solutions are not working for me and I don't understand why. Here's my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^pages\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L,NE]
```

The aim is to enforce https, but not for the 'pages' subdomain (whose content is in a subdirectory of this htaccess file, so I assume it's inheriting the rules).

This is not having the expected effect and all requests to 'http://pages.example.com/foo' are getting redirected to 'https://example.com/foo'.

Comment: Clear your browser cache once before applying the rules.

Comment: That actually worked! But my browser can't cache a redirect rule, only a specific redirect, am I right?